# How can I multiply arrays and print the result as a matrix in perl?

Tags: arrays, perl

I am new to Perl and would like to multiply two arrays:

```
my @array1 = (1,2,3);
my @array2 = (2,4,6);
```

and print out as such:

```
      # output ==
      #          2  4  6
      #          4  8 12
      #          6 12 18
```

edit:

Got it

```
my @array1 = (1,2,3);
my @array2 = (2,4,6);

multiply_array(\@array1, \@array2);

sub multiply_array{
     my ($a1, $a2)=@_;
     for(my $i=0; $i<3; $i++){
         for(my $j=0; $j<3; $j++){
             my $x = @$a1[$i]*@$a2[$j];
             print $x."\t";
        }
         print "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: that's a sloppy way to do it; `@$a1[$i]*@$a2[$j]` does two array slices; you just want array elements: `$$a1[$i]*$$a2[$i]` (or `$a1->[$i]*$a2->[$j]`)

Answer (score 5):

The operation you are trying to do on the arrays is called a cartesian product.

Creating an array of arrays with the cartesian product:

```
my @product = map { my $a = $_; [map { $_ * $a } @array2] } @array1;
```

Printing it in a very verbose format:

```
use Data::Dumper;
Dumper(@product);
```

Just printing the product without storing it into an array:

```
for my $x (@array1) {
    for my $y (@array2) {
        print $x * $y . "\t";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

Comment: How can I create an array of arrays with this?

Answer (score 0):

You have passed references of the arrays to the function.

Hence you need to use `->` to access the array elements.

Here's what you can do:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array1 = (1,2,3);
my @array2 = (2,4,6);

multiply_array(\@array1, \@array2);

sub multiply_array{
    my ($a1, $a2)=@_;
    for(my $i=0; $i<3; $i++){
        for(my $j=0; $j<3; $j++){
            my $x = $a1->[$i]*$a2->[$j];
            print $x."\t";
        }
        print "\n";
    }
}
```